# Авторизация на домене и получение контента

Tags: curl, php, cookie

Не могу разобраться с curl. Надо авторизоваться по URL http://www.mysite.ru/login.php, получить кукки, и далее эти кукки передать скрипту http://www.mysite.ru/some.php и показать на браузере то что выдаст последний скрипт.

Покажите на примере, пожалуйста, не догоняю малость как получать кукки и передать в другой скрипт. Доки читал, не разобрался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так, для начала вам нужно авторизоваться на сайте http://mysite.ru/login.php и получить от туда куки. Это можно сделать вот так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.ru/login.php'); //url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); // отсюда будут читаться куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt"); // сюда будут писаться куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Test UA');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); // указываем что будет отправляться POST запрос ( Если он нужен для авторизации на сайте, конечно).
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=KryDos&password=qwerty');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Если авторизация прошла успешно то в файле "cookie.txt" будут сохранены куки, которые вы хотите передать на  http://www.mysite.ru/some.php.

Теперь по аналогии делаем так:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.ru/some.php'); //url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); // отсюда будут читаться куки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt"); // сюда будут писаться куки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Test UA');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Теперь в переменной $data будет то что вернул бы браузер при обращении к mysite.ru/some.php.

Comment: Отлично, работает. Странно, я таким образом авторизовался, но думал что куки потеряются, если иницилизировать другой курл...